# Are there rules on messages for keeping a chatroom alive?

Tags: support, chat

I stumbled over a chatroom where the majority of the recent messages are only to keep the room alive. Before I asked this question [I went ahead and bookmarked an example](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124882/conversation/example).

Are there any rules on keeping a chatroom alive like this? If there are rules against it, what is the appropriate action to take against it?

Comment: I don't see a downside/problem if a room owner wants to keep an unused room alive and also the room title is bot testing(not sure if it is used for that purpose).

Comment: @suraj the example has not been used for bot testing in a long time. But the example is an example, I'm asking for the general rules on this topic

Comment: Fair enough. My primary question or rather confusion is regarding the problem with someone doing this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there are no rules, [there is a philosophy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270587/).

We should only invent rules and enforce them once there turns out to be a problem.

Having rooms that are kept alive by a single user or bot don't seem to be a problem on the Stack Overflow chat server. Chat traffic is so high that such rooms only be on the top active tab for a short while.

I can only imagine this might be an issue on low traffic sites where the artificially kept alive room is more active then the main room. But even that is more of a sign of a different problem.

With SOCVR we have a [test room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68414/socvr-testing-facility) as well that is kept alive by a message now and then. We also have an extra room for our [room meetings](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/108179). We let that room simply get frozen and then ask a moderator to warm it up when we have a meeting.

Creating rooms is free so if keeping it alive is somehow restricted that would lead to the creation of more new rooms and then we have to regulate that.

The current system and approach works and if no clear abuse vector is eminent nothing needs to done.